# Numbers stored as text in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with a SampleID, a DataTypeID, and a DataValue.  The SampleID and DataTypeID are numeric (for now, DataTypeID may change), and DataValue is a varchar(20).  I store numbers and text in this table.  When I query, everything returns as expected, but when I want to do math on the values, I haven't found a good way to check if the DataValue is not null, and is numeric.  I have to check both.  I can use something like `CDbl([DataValue])`, which works great if it is a number, but I have to check that first... so it ends up being...

`IIf(IsNumeric([DataValue]),cdbl([DataValue]),[DataValue])`

...and that just isn't very pretty.

I am pulling the data values in a primary query, before doing the math, and I hoped that I could set the data to a number there (using the second example above), but it doesn't carry over the same as if the [DataValue] was set to float.

Is there something else I can try to make my secondary query/math on [DataValue] work if it is a number, and ignore if it is not?  I know it is a number, but I don't know if it is null (and it can change as data is entered).  So it is more about changing known numbers using `Cdbl()` and dealing with the errors if the DataValue is null.  Any ideas I can try?

`EDIT:`  Here is some additional information.  The 'math' that I am doing with these datavalues is as such.  The datavalues are from a timed process (10hr, 20hr, 30hr, etc.)  I have a second table that has parameters that the value needs to be within at each time... so I link those two tables on the time value, then compare like such...

`DataValueFlag: IIf([DataValue]<[LowerParameter],-1,IIf([DataValue]>[UpperParameter],-1,0))`

When I look at the report, it will show all the times (even if they don't exist yet)... so then the `DataValueFlag` tries to calculate for all the times.  If DataValue is stored as float, it works great.  If DataValue is stored as varchar, it causes an error.  If I add `Cdbl()` to DataValue, it works fine as long as there is a value, but for the upcoming hour samples where DataValue is missing (I don't think it is really null... maybe just empty?), it causes an error.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server if your question concerns MS Access?

Comment: How about the `Nz` function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: Pretty or not, basically stuck with that IIf() due to mixing data types in field. IsNumeric() returns False if field is Null. What calc are you using DataValue in that would error on Null or string? Can handle Null with Nz() function. Maybe need to build a VBA custom function.

Comment: When you do the SELECT, you can test for NULL. Also, you should strive to not mix NULL, Numeric data and non-Numeric data all in one column. Relational databases are not designed to perform well on such column.

Comment: @nochance Thanks for the suggestion - and I misspoke... I am storing numeric and non-numeric... no values are null.  As described above in the edit, the values are just missing (so maybe they count as empty).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Nz* and *Val* to return 0 (zero) for non-numeric values:

```
NumValue: Val(Nz([DataValue]))
```

Comment: return of 0 would not help in this situation since I am comparing a value to an upper/lower limit.  0 would probably be lower that the low limit in most cases, thus flagging the data as out of range, even though it is really empty.

Comment: Then filter out the non-numeric values - as @NoChance suggested.

Comment: I can (and have) filtered out the non-numeric values, but since the table stores the data as text this 
`IIf([DataValue]<[LowerParameter],-1,IIf([DataValue]>[UpperParameter],-1,0))` 
fails when it evaluates DataValue as an empty string (rather than null).  Is there an easy way to set empty strings to null instead?

Comment: If (as) you filter out non-numeric values, these cannot be an empty string. So ..?